# SQL Server - Compare Varchar values using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my table, I have a varchar column whereby multi-values are stored. An example of my table:

```
RecNum           |  Title   |  Category
-----------------------------------------
wja-2012-000001  |  abcdef  |  4,6
wja-2012-000002  |  qwerty  |  1,3,7
wja-2012-000003  |  asdffg  |   
wja-2012-000004  |  zxcvbb  |  2,7
wja-2012-000005  |  ploiuh  |  3,4,12
```

The values in the `Category` column points to another table.

How can I return the relevant rows if I want to retrieve the rows with value 1,3,5,6,8 in the Category column?

When I tried using IN, I get the 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,3,5,6,8' to data type int' error.

Comment: Do you have control of the database design and layout. If so, it would probably be better to add an ID column to this table, then add another table that maps categories to IDs. Then you just need to join the tables.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the answers given. I do not have control over the design of the tables, hence the headache here. Otherwise I would have normalize the table further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking the Categories out into a separate table would be a better design if that's a change you can make... otherwise, you could create a function to split the values into a table of integers like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))
returns @temptable TABLE (id int)
as
begin
    declare @idx int
    declare @slice varchar(8000)

    select @idx = 1
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return

    while @idx!= 0
    begin
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
        if @idx!=0
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)
        else
            set @slice = @String

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            insert into @temptable(id) values(convert(int, @slice))

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)
        if len(@String) = 0 break
    end
return
end
```

Then call it from your query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE @SomeID IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.Split(Category, ','))
```

Or if you're looking to provide a list of categories as an input parameter (such as '1,3,5,6,8'), and return all records in your table that contain at least one of these values, you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        select 1
        from dbo.Split(Category, ',') s1
        join dbo.Split(@SearchValues, ',') s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

> declare @var varchar(30); set @var='2,3';
>
> exec('select * from category where Category_Id in ('+@var+')')

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE test4(RecNum varchar(20),Title varchar(10),Category varchar(15))
INSERT INTO test4
VALUES('wja-2012-000001','abcdef','4,6'),
('wja-2012-000002','qwerty','1,3,7'),
('wja-2012-000003','asdffg',null),   
('wja-2012-000004','zxcvbb','2,7'),
('wja-2012-000005','ploiuh','3,4,12')

select * from test4
Declare @str varchar(25) = '1,3,5,6,8'
;WITH CTE as (select RecNum,Title,Category from test4)
,CTE1 as (
select RecNum,Title,RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(',',@str,1)) as rem from CTE where category like '%'+LEFT(@str,1)+'%' 
union all
select c.RecNum,c.Title,RIGHT(c1.rem,LEN(c1.rem)-CHARINDEX(',',c1.rem,1)) as rem from CTE1 c1 inner join CTE c 
on c.category like '%'+LEFT(c1.rem,1)+'%' and CHARINDEX(',',c1.rem,1)>0
 )
 select RecNum,Title from CTE1
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others, your table design violates basic database design principles and if there is no way around it, you could normalize the table with little code (example below) and then join away with the other table. Here you go:

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE data(RecNum varchar(20),Title varchar(10),Category varchar(15))
INSERT INTO data
VALUES('wja-2012-000001','abcdef','4,6'),
('wja-2012-000002','qwerty','1,3,7'),
('wja-2012-000003','asdffg',null),   
('wja-2012-000004','zxcvbb','2,7'),
('wja-2012-000005','ploiuh','3,4,12')
```

This function takes a comma separated string and returns a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION listToTable (@list nvarchar(MAX))
   RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
           @nextpos    int,
           @valuelen   int

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
   RETURN
END
```

Then, you can do something like this to "normalize" the table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   data m
CROSS  APPLY  listToTable(m.Category) AS t
where Category is not null
```

And then use the result of the above query to join with the "other" table. For example (i did not test this query):

```
select * from otherTable a
join listToTable('1,3,5,6,8') b
on a.Category = b.number
join(

    SELECT *
    FROM   data m
    CROSS  APPLY  listToTable(m.Category) AS t
    where Category is not null
    ) c
on a.category = c.number
```

Comment: this is basically the same answer as drumboog's

Comment: I agree that it is similar, but not "the same." The idea was to demonstrate a way to convert an original denormalized table into something usable; which is the part with the CROSS APPLY. Then use the result in queries with JOINS vs. an IN statement. IMO it is more flexible.